# Diferencia entre consiguiente y consecuencia

Tags: definiciones, sustantivos

Cita de *Cuestiones Místicas* por el p. Gonzalez Arintero, nota p. 65 :

> Y él, a pesar de todo, se resuelve, como luego veremos, por la
> afirmativa.— Muy gustosos le admitimos el consiguiente, pero...
> negando tal consecuencia.

(en https://archive.org/details/cuestionesmsti00arinuoft/page/65/mode/1up )

No entiendo la segunda frase, ¿por qué *consiguiente* y *consecuencia* me parecen ser la misma cosa ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Y él, a pesar de todo, se resuelve, como luego veremos, por la
> afirmativa.— Muy gustosos le admitimos el consiguiente, pero...
> negando tal consecuencia.

*¿ No entiendo la segunda frase, porque consiguiente y consecuencia me parecen ser la misma cosa ?*

- Lo "**Consiguiente**" es la descripción de la relación causal entre una cosa y otra. Relación que puede ser establecida de manera cierta, o por el contrario, ser establecida erróneamente.
- La "**Consecuencia**" es el resultado o efecto de algo, más allá de la relación establecida.

La frase, resumidamente expresa de una parte, estar de acuerdo con una relación causal que se establece, sin embargo, no esta de acuerdo o niega que la consecuencia o el resultado que se deriva de esa relación, sea el fijado por ese autor.

---

> Muy gustosos le admitimos el consiguiente, pero... negando tal
> consecuencia.

Muy gustosos le admitimos **el consiguiente** (*la relación establecida entre los estados sobrenaturales de oración, los medios de santificación y las gracias de santidad*), pero... negando tal **consecuencia** (*negando el resultado de esa relación, ya que confunde los estados sobrenaturales de oración con los términos de gracias extraordinarias, privilegios y privanzas divinas*).

(*Ya que los estados sobrenaturales de oración, entendidos bajo el prisma de ese autor, podría caber la duda (si o no), de ser considerados como presuntuosos*).

Comment: Gracias. No puse upvote a esta respuesta porque no puedo ainda, no tengo suficientes pontos

Comment: ¡Gracias a ti! No te preocupes, yo si te he podido dar un voto positivo, lo importante es que vayas adentrándote poco a poco. ¡Bienvenido!

Comment: @Charles2023 No puedo **todavia**. ainda es portugués.

Comment: @Lambie Entendí, gracias